# Generate a code every x hours that will always be the same in two machines?

Tags: php, random, code-generation

Considering that the two machine's time settings are not synced, is it still possible to run a PHP script (for example) in each of them and they will still generate the same random code when run every x hours?

For example:

If I run the script in server A on 1PM it will return "random182".
If I run the script in server B on 1PM it will return "random182".

If I run the script in server A on 2PM it will return "random747".
If I run the script in server B on 2PM it will return "random747".

If it's possible, how and what sort of functions should I be looking at?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what code do you want to generate?

Comment: @xdazz just a random code like the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The machines need a common [initialisation vector (IV)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) for their pseudo-random sequence.

Classically this is system time (if security is unimportant).  So:

- synchronise your time e.g. [ntp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) (at an app or machine level)
- or pass in the IV to your script when you call it, i.e. the callee is saying what the IV is

Comment: I second this. If you use a preudo-random generator, use time as its seed. You just have to be sure both systems are time-synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

PHP  time is returned according to the specified value in the php.ini file . So first calculate the difference then add that to the time which runs 'late' and then output whatever you like .